# css - Card block, how to position and size image

Tags: css

I'm having problems finding the best way to position and size the image in the example here.

I want the image to be positioned on the far right and be resized so it fits inside the containing block.

Is `position` the best way to position and how can I resize it to fit within the block. I want the image proportional scaled to fit

```css
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.block__body{
  padding: 10px ;
}

.block__img{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

    <div class="block__body">
        <div>
            <h3 class="block__heading">
                Heading Text
            </h3>
            <p class="block__copy">Copy Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block__img">
        <img
            src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals"
            alt="placeholder image"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my code . With the [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) property, you can put them in one row. To scale the image with respect to the screen size and for better responsiveness, you can add the [vw and vh](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) to that.

And you don't need the [position property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003594/12210002) for this when you have the flex property.

```css
* {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .block {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        margin: 10px;
        height: 35vh;

        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .block__body {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: baseline;
      }

      .block__img img {
        width: 40vw;
        /*height: 30vh;*/
        height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block__body">
        <h3 class="block__heading">
          Heading Text
        </h3>
        <p class="block__copy">Copy Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="block__img">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502899845910-573a1d1c390d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9"
          alt="placeholder image"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to limit the height of the div and image, otherwise it will be shown in the original image size.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.block__body {
  padding: 10px ;
}

.block__img {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

For the `<img>`, you can put it inline:

```html
<img
  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals"
  alt="placeholder image"
  height="100%"
/>
```

Or in the CSS:

```css
.block__img img {
  height: 100%;
}
```